# Re-deploy AWS CloudWatch Logs with serverless framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I deployed an AWS service using the serverless framework, which created and deployed all the resources automatically.

But later on I accidentally deleted the log group for this service, and no logs are beeing created anymore.

Is there a way to recreate / redeploy just the log-group resource, because serverless --remove & serverless --deploy would delete all existing resources and create new ones which would be bad in my case.

Any ideas?

Comment: any solution to this yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment out the function in serverless.yml, deploy, uncomment the function and deploy again. As far as I can tell, serverless tries to remove the log group when you "remove" the function and then create it when you "add" the function.

Also, afaict, you have to actually deploy. You can't just save, you have to do the full stack update for serverless to notice.

Answer (score 0):

```
sls deploy -f <function name>
```

Or you can manually just create the log groups for now

Comment: Deploying just the function did not solve the problem and manually creating the log group with the same name did not work either.

Comment: Hmm did the IAM role for cloudwatch disappear?

Comment: I am having the same issue here